# document.forms[0] is undefined in Firefox

Tags: javascript

```
var viewMode = document.forms[0].viewGroupFlag.value;
var moveFlg = document.forms[0].moveGrpFlag.value;
```

the above code is my javascript and i set `viewGroupFlag` and `moveGrpFlag` as hidden variables in my JSP

`document.forms[0]` is undefined in Firefox for first line in JS but it works in internet explorer and Google Chrome.

kindly provide the solution please.

Comment: Can we see your `HTML`?

Comment: If there are no form tags, there will be no form[0]

Comment: It could be that you are accessing `forms` before it is created. You can execute the JS code after body `onload` event. Difficult to know exact reason. Post minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: How can we provide 'the solution' to a problem we can't see? We *need* to see the relevant HTML.

Comment: I suspect that Java Script code may be completed before form gets loaded. That might be the reason why FF cannot find document.forms[0]. Please try to access values of your form once page is loaded completely. For example inside JQuery -- $( document ).ready(function() {

Answer (score 2):

Why not give your form an id and select it that way? You won't have to worry about form indices which could potentially change in the future. Do something like so:

HTML:

```
<form id="form_id">
....
</form>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form_id');
//do stuff with form.whatever
```

Comment: Cerbrus, you're like my guardian angel <3

Comment: Why not directly get to `document.getElementById('viewGroupFlag').value;`?

Comment: @SeanCoker: I just edit what I think could be improved :P
Hanky: In this case, that'd work, but it's usually a good idea to save the form in a variable, if you're gonna access multiple properties.

Comment: And given the OP does not consider showing the code, it is likely the fields have names and not IDs so getElementById will work in IE and fail in others

Comment: I accept this, but my doubt is the immediate next line which has same kind of code is working fine.